# Call INSERT function inline from script

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently using Postgres and I want to create a connivence function to cut down on some repetition in my scripts.

I have a function defined as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION add_entry(i smallint, m varchar, t varchar) RETURNS VOID AS $$
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO metrics(id, medium, metric) VALUES (i, m, t);
  END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I then want to call the function in my script as follows:

```
SELECT add_entry(3, "hello", "world");
```

When I call the script with the function definition at the beginning of the script followed by subsequent calls to the function, the following error is generated:

```
psql:static-data.sql:7: ERROR:  function "add_entry" already exists with same argument types
SELECT "add_entry"(3, "hello", "world");
psql:static-data.sql:9: ERROR:  column "hello" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "add_entry"(3, "hello", "world");
```

The problem appears that when I call the function, it's behaving like a redefinition of the function.

How do I solve this issue and directly call the function? Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to create the function once. You can think of it like this: a function is part of the schema, just like a table. You wouldn't create a table every time you run your script, so why create the function every time then?

Now, if you really have to redefine the function you can do it like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_entry...
```

This will delete the old definition and create a new one in its place.

Comment: Ah this makes sense. Is there a way to force redefinition of the function. Like drop the previous function and redefine it?

Comment: Perfect, I see your updated answer; thank you so much!

Comment: @JamesTaylor Note that `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` can be picky sometimes, e.g. it won't allow you to simply change the name of a variable. So sometimes, you might have to do just drop the function first.